# How to set views frame without auto layout

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios6

With the release of iOS 6 I changed my applications storyboard to use the new auto layout feature.

My problem is that I set a tableview frame in one view controller - but when I use the auto layout feature the table.frame = CGRectMake(..) code seems to get ignored.

My app should change the tableview frame if there is iAd or no iAd.

[image: the tableview is to heigh - we have to change that.]

I dont know if i can solve this problem with auto layout - maybe you can help me.

greetings from germany :)

Comment: That is expected. You should try to add a constraint for your view that gives it the correct size and position.

Comment: Is there a possibily to change this constraint? Because the way I want to work the View is: 1.) Check if the user has paid for no ads 2.) If yes, dont change the tableview - if no, reduce the height of the tableview

Comment: You can add and remove constants in code using `addConstraint:`

Comment: I searched for a while now, but I dont find how to just dynamically change the height of the tableview :/

Comment: Your table view should have constraints that tell its edges to stay a fixed distance from the edges of the superview or something similar. If you insert and iAd view then you should instead change the bottom constraint to tell the table view to stay a fixed distance from the top of the iAd view.

Comment: thanks so far, I finally just assigned an IBOutlet to the height constraint of my tableview and now I can just set the tableview height with tableviewConstraint.constant = value; Thanks for sending me into the right direction ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but with the move to iOS7 I felt it was time to activate auto-layout for my own apps.  I ran across this and found that I could simply turn auto-layout back on and put your `table.frame = CGRectMake(..)` code into:

```
- (void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
table.frame = CGRectMake(..)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Don't use the auto layout and remove the `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth` and `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleheight` in the xib. Let me know if you didn't get it.

And use the set frame property in the code.

Comment: Thats the problem, I have to use auto layout in other views - and unfortunately there isn't a possibility to turn auto layout off for certain views.

Comment: Seems like I have misunderstood something? I'um using xcode 4.5